# How can I execute a method inside mybatis mapper?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

```
        <if test="group_id != null">
            <choose>
                <when test='group_id.get("eq") != null'>
                    and roleobj.object_id = ${group_id.get("eq")} 
                </when>
            </choose>
        </if>
```

I am passing Map<String, Map<String, String>> inside mybatis, as a parameter. However, when i am trying to make dynamic sql using it, it's not working properly, and usually results in an error. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Use `#{}` instead of `${}` whenever possible. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-). It's super important for you to understand the difference. Anyway, if the key is known, you can just write `... = #{group_id.eq}`.

Comment: @ave Thanks! But I am now getting errors in <when> tag. Changed in to <when test= "group_id.eq != null">, and getting following error "Error evaluating expression 'group_id.eq != null'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: group_id.eq != null".
All data is present in the Map parameter, like {"group_id" : {"eq" : "100"}}

Comment: You should not change `<when />`. Expressions in `test` attribute and `${}` are evaluated by OGNL.